# Copying a list into a numpy array converts floats into strings

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list with 4 columns, 3 of which are np.floats and 1 of them is a str, when i run this

```
print("cluster", clusters[0], type(clusters[0][0]))
numpyClusters = np.copy(clusters)
print("numpyCluster", numpyClusters[0], type(numpyClusters[0][0]))
finalizedClusters = kMeansAlgorithm(dataSet, centeroids, clusters, oldClusters, k)
```

it prints

```
cluster [0.12072145106500658, 1, 1.0337254896570043, 'winter'] <class 'numpy.float64'>
numpyCluster ['0.12072145106500658' '1' '1.0337254896570043' 'winter'] <class 'numpy.str_'>
```

Later on i need the first 3 columns to be floats,
Can you copy a list into a numpy array with all the values inside keeping their original type?

Comment: A numpy array has 1 data type, while a python list can hold elements with different data types. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @couka, a numpy array can only have one type of data in it. Though, you can cheat a little, for numpy allows the `object` dtype. For instance:

```python
>>> import numpy as np

>>> test = ["a", 1, 2, 3]
>>> test_array = np.array(test)
>>> test_array
array(['a', '1', '2', '3'], dtype='<U1')
>>> test_array * 2
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U3'), dtype('<U3')) -> dtype('<U3')
>>> test_array_object = np.array(test, dtype="O")
>>> test_array_object
array(['a', 1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
>>> test_array_object * 2
array(['aa', 2, 4, 6], dtype=object)
```

When the `dtype` of the array is `object` and an operation is performed, numpy will simply apply the corrersponding operation on its elements. For instance, when multiplying an array with an integer, numpy will call the `__mul__` method of each object in the array.

This method has several drawbacks though. If you only want to apply the operation on the integers, you have to do some indexing:

```python
>>> test_array_object[1:] *= 2
>>> test_array_object
array(['a', 2, 4, 6], dtype=object)
```

More importantly, numpy can't use every optimization it usually uses for integer arrays, so you would have a cost overhead in speed execution by doing so.

I think the simplest method is to simply use a dataclass to hold your data and define the operations you want to apply on it, like this:

```python
from dataclasses impoort dataclass

import numpy as np

@dataclass
class NamedArray:
    name: str
    array: np.ndarray
```

which you would then use like this:

```python
>>> test = ["a", 1., 2., 3.]
>>> named_test = NamedArray(test[0], np.array(test[1:]))
>>> named_test
NamedArray(name='a', array=array([1, 2, 3]))
>>> named_test.array
array([1., 2., 3.])
>>> named_test.array.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

You are then to free to work with `named_test.array` to do your computations on an array, while keeping numpy's optimizations on the operations you perform and without having to care about the `str` held in `named_test.name`.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html (Emphasis mine)

> ```
> numpy.array(object, dtype=None, *, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0, like=None)
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> dtype : data-type, optional The desired data-type for the array. **If
> not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type
> required to hold the objects in the sequence.**

Since you can represent any float as a string, but not vice-versa, numpy decides to use strings for everything when initialized with a mixed list of floats and strings.